# How to use removeEventListener to disable addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.style.height = "100px"
element.style.width = "100px";
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(element);

function hov() {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
element.addEventListener('mouseover', hov);
element.removeEventListener('mouseout', hov);
```

As you can see, I created div element with red background color. AddEventListener works fine, the background color is changed to blue, but why removeEventListener doesn't work? Why div is still blue?

Comment: You will need to create a function to return the color back to red.

Comment: There is no event registered for `'mouseout'` so `removeEventListener` will not not remove an event. If it would work, it still would not change your color back do red. you would need another function that sets the color to red on mouseout. btw you can use css for that `div:hover {background: blue;}`

Comment: First of all you are not removing the listener (*you need to use the same event you bound to*) but you do not have to. Removing the listener will not unde what happened inside the listener. You just need to **add** one more handler for the mouseout event that undoes what the first one did.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I know that's possible with the usage of two functions (first to add and second to remove). I was wondering is that possible to make it with the way that I show in my question. The answer is "no" :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a function to return the color back to red:

```
function hovOut() { 
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
} 
element.addEventListener('mouseout', hovOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

You removed event listener, that means, The div wont listen to any further "hover" events. 
So you need to add another function to (other than removeeventlistener) change the color, based on the condition

Answer (score 0):

the thing about event is once its fired it finished what it does. removing the event listner doesn't cancel that what was done in response to it ( your case it was hov function)

what happened was:
1. event emitted -> function hov did its part
2. removed listener -> code stopped waiting for mouseout event

no such mouseout event was defined

a workaround:

```
function removeHov(){
   element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
element.addEventListener('mouseout', removeHov);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not successfully remove the event listener, and even if you did, the colour of the div has also been changed. Its colour will not change back only because you detach the event. Instead, you need to explicitly change the colour.